# SQLPLUS use optional parameters

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

Currently, I call an SQL File from a CMD file and transfer some parameters during the call. The code below works if I actually pass a value or press enter. However, my CMD/SQL will stop and wait for the parameter if there was none given. In such a case I would like to continue with default values instead.

CMD Code:

```
REM this works
sqlplus !dbuser! @!some_dir!\some_sql_file.sql test_text >> !log!

REM this STOPS and waits until user interaction happens
sqlplus !dbuser! @!some_dir!\some_sql_file.sql >> !log!
```

SQL Code:

```
set serveroutput on

SET LINESIZE 10000

declare
    l_some_text varchar2(1000);
begin

     select nvl('&&3','no_text_given') into l_some_text from dual;

    dbms_output.enable;
    dbms_lock.sleep(1);
    dbms_output.put_line('SQL uses: ' || l_some_text );

end ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter can't be `3`; there's only one, so it is supposed to be `1`.

---

Here's option you might be interested in.

`a.sql` file:

```
set serveroutput on
set ver off

set termout off
  column 1 new_value 1
  select null as "1" from dual where 1 = 2;
set termout on

declare
    l_some_text varchar2(1000);
begin
   select nvl('&1', 'no_text_given') into l_some_text from dual;
   dbms_output.put_line('SQL uses: ' || l_some_text );
end ;
/
exit;
```

Let's test it: **with parameter** passed to it:

```
c:\temp>sqlplus -s scott/tiger@pdb1 @a.sql littlefoot
SQL uses: littlefoot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**Without parameter**:

```
c:\temp>sqlplus -s scott/tiger@pdb1 @a.sql
SQL uses: no_text_given

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


c:\temp>
```

---

Adjust it, if you have to (e.g. redirect to file; remove various `set`tings I used, ...) but - generally - that's what you asked for.

Comment: Hi Littlefoot, sorry for the &3 - I actually used more parameters and failed to simplify correctly. So basically, the VER and TERMOUT are what I was missing. I will test this and come back.

Answer (score 0):

In `cmd`,

```
if not defined parameter set "parameter=defaultvalue"
sqlplus !dbuser! @!some_dir!\some_sql_file.sql !parameter! >> !log!
```

if `parameter` has not been set, uses default. You haven't shown us how you provide `test_text` to the `cmd` procedure; you would need to assign its value to `parameter`

Comment: Hi, Magoo. Basically, I want to provide generic tools for me and my colleagues. So "test_text" would be one of the parameters that we hardcode when calling some_sql_file.sql. It might be convenient to skip the last parameter once in a while.